# Remover 0 de resultado de fecha

Tags: sql, sql-server

Realizo este comando para traerme la fecha en un formato YYYY/MM/DD:

```
DECLARE @SomeExampleDate DATETIME;
SELECT @SomeExampleDate = '2016/08/20';

SELECT STUFF(REPLACE('/'+CONVERT(CHAR(10),@SomeExampleDate,102), '.', '/'),1,1,'')
```

Pero quiero que la fecha que me regresa no incluya los ceros (0) antes del día o mes en caso de tener. Utilizo SQL-Server 2014 Express.

Comment: Versión de SQL?

Comment: SQL Server 2014 Express

Comment: Con 2014, format es la mejor opción como dijo Aprendiendo.NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se puede usar la función [Format()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hh213505.aspx):

```
DECLARE @SomeExampleDate DATETIME
SELECT @SomeExampleDate = '2016/08/20'

SELECT FORMAT(@SomeExampleDate, 'yyyy/M/d')
```